# XSLT - curly braces in regex

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have a text node from which I have to extract a particular sub string based on a pattern

Below is the actual string:

```
//Some_string,&quot;some_string_1&quot;:&quot;target_string&quot;},some_other_string//
```

Following is the regex pattern I am trying to use:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="text_node/text()" regex=",(&quot;some_string_1&quot;:.*?)&quot;}">
    <xsl:matching-substring>    
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(regex-group(1),':&quot;')"/>          
    </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

My extracted sub string should be "target_string"

But I am getting the following error

```
Fatal error during transformation using //my_path: Closing curly brace in attribute value template ",("some_string_1":.*?)"}" must be doubled;
```

I tried to use double curly braces also but didn't work

Note - I am using Ant script to run the XSLT with saxon-he-10.1.jar

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens exactly when you double the curly brace? You only say "I tried to use double curly braces also but didn't work" but don't explain which error you get then or if your regular expression simply doesn't match. In general, I tend to put the pattern into e.g. `<xsl:param name="pattern" as="xs:string">pattern goes here</xsl:param>` and then use `regex="{$pattern}"` as that way you need a lot less escaping.

Comment: Trying to reduce your sample to a minimal example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Mvnt3R it seems after doubling the curly brace the string is extracted.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to put regular expressions into an `xs:string` typed parameter or variable e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="pattern" as="xs:string">,("some_string_1":(.*?))"}</xsl:param>
```

then I can use

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$pattern}">
    <xsl:matching-substring>    
        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>          
    </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

where I have a lot less to worry about escaping things in an attribute value template like the `regex` attribute.

Note, that, if you use XSLT 3, it is safer to have

```
<xsl:param name="pattern" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">,("some_string_1":(.*?))"}</xsl:param>
```

to avoid any text value template setting higher up in the tree kicking in.

Comment: I still needed to escape the curly braces:

`<variable name="pattern"  as="xs:string" expand-text="no">\{.+?\}</variable>
    <analyze-string select="." regex="{$pattern}">
     ...
    </analyze-string>`

Comment: @o-sapov, that's true. The is also the `q` flag but it would escape all your used characters for the sample e.g. `\{\.\+\?\}` so for that example the `q` flag wouldn't help.

Comment: Ok, thank you for info.
Anyway, this apporaach spares the double curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

You need to double the curly bracket because it has special meaning in XSLT and escape it because it has special meaning in regex:

```
",(&quot;some_string_1&quot;:.*?)&quot;\}}"
```